# Flutter: How to center text with dynamic length?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hello I have created a custom appbar where the title of appbar will come from API which can any of the length so How can I center it.

code of custom appbar,

```
class CustomAppBar extends PreferredSize {
  final String title;
  final double height;
  CustomAppBar({
    @required this.title,
    this.height = kToolbarHeight,
  });
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(height);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final headline6 = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6;
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 99,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            AppColors.veryDarkBlue,
            AppColors.blueWhale,
          ],
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          stops: [
            0.3,0.8
          ],
        ),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 27,
        left: 19,
      ),
      child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 20.sdpHeight,
                  ),
                  onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      title,                  //<--- I want to align this
                      style: headline6.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
         )
    );
  }
}
```

how it looks,

[image]

[image]

in second screen shot it has little more gap on left then it should be so How I can fix it?

Comment: Put an SizedBox with the same size as the back button on the right side.

Comment: @lsaudon ok that actually works never thought solution will be this simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add something to take up the space from right just as your icon

```
 children: [
                    InkWell(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 20.sdpHeight,
                      ),
                      onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          title,                  //<--- I want to align this
                          style: headline6.copyWith(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  SizedBox(width:40.0),
                  ],
```

Comment: as said in the comment thank you for putting it in the code